# When is document (word, pdf) metadata used

Tags: 2010, 2007, managed-metadata, search-results, metadata

In 2007, when I indexed word and PDF content the search results displayed the author (created by) and a description (description column) from the actual library.

In 2010, I am getting the content from the actual PDF or word document, which is different from the library.

How can I stop the later happening. I could and should get the document metadata changed but i cant see the client being keen.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Office documents i-filters are already provided with SharePoint to index content of documents while crawling. I suppose in SharePoint 2010 administrator must have been installed the iFilters for PDF files which is free to download and install. You would need to remove those iFilters, however bear in mind that such operation affects the entire farm.

Properties exposed via Search Core Results (change XML properties via Edit web part), after being promoted from crawled properties (automatically indexed properties from columns from content types) to search managed properties in SPCA - same concepts apply to SharePoint 2007/2010.

You could alternativelly (however that would mean entirelly hiding them from search) to remove confidential content by using library settings and un-check where where it says to make content available for search. Other alternative is also to modify your search scopes to remove those documents (or extensions) via rules.

Comment: Just to be clear I am the admin and I have installed the foxit ifilter to deal with PDFs. What i mean is that in 2007 the metadata displayed in searches came from the metadata in the list or library. In 2010 the metadata is from the document itself.